# Square in a quadrant of a circle (Doubt in a solution given)

Tags: geometry, circles

From the MindYourDecisions video ["Challenging problem given to 12 year olds - square in a quadrant"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ECHpJueKN7c) on YouTube:

**Original question:-**

[image]

**I have a doubt in the solution given:-** Make 3 additional copies and complete the circle.  There will be 5 squares in the shape of a +. One of the diameters of the circle will intersect the outer corners of 2 outer squares.

I have made a very rough diagram following what has being said, I get a shape of +.  After that I am confused.  {The purple, yellow, and orange squares are the ones I got by symmetry}

[image]

Let $s = \text{side of square}$.  That diameter will be the hypotenuse of a right triangle ($2$).  The legs are $s$ and $3s$.  So,
$$10s^2 = 4\to s^2 = 2/5$$

Comment: Your answer of $2/5$ matches the video's answer of $0.4$, so what's your question? If you're wondering if your approach is correct: it is. (And I consider it an improvement over the one shown in the video.) Congratulations to you! (Or, congratulations to the person whose YouTube comment included that solution.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> "...I have made a very rough diagram following what has being said, I get a shape of +. After that I am confused."

So I guess this is what you are asking about:

[image]

Apply Pythagoras' theorem to the obvious right triangle.

$$(3s)^2+s^2=2^2$$

Comment: Why do I need 10 rep to post images? :\

Comment: To avoid spam accounts, and to not overly burden the image hosting site.

Comment: So every circular sector would have an inscribed square. Do we have a nice formula for the side in terms of $r$ and $\theta$ ( the central angle)?

Comment: @orangeskid , I don't think there is a 'nice' formula. But it can be easily derived using the method described in the video above. The method in my answer (actually it is not mine) can not give a formula for every $\theta$.